# Facebook post_box element. I cant find element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Facebook post_box element. I cant find element by xpath

Hi,
I learn to write automation test scripts in Selenium Webdriver with Python. I will make "Facebook Poster script". After login i wanna click in SendBox and sent some text, but i cant identyfing it with Xpath. Firebug not help mi with this. Thx for help.

Something like this:

## After login

```
newpost=driver.find_element_by_xpath("i dont know correct xpath")
newpost.click()
newpost.send_keys("Hello!")
newpost.submit()
```

Xpath from Firebug not working

```
newpost = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div")
```

Comment: Frankly I would hope they would make it so their site (Facebook) didn't work with WebDriver at all as to prevent bots/spam. Since I assume you don't work for Facebook, if you are looking for sites to learn on try this: http://www.techbeamers.com/websites-to-practice-selenium-webdriver-online/
 Or if you are creating bots/spam.... I can't really wish you much success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution:

```
newpost = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name='xhpc_message']")
newpost.click()
newpost.send_keys("Hello!")
newpost.submit()
```

@GVi thx for help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use absolute xpath - it's costly to maintain and looks just horrible.

As I understand, you need to click on input field with the placeholder 'what's on your mind'. Then you can get use of 'data-testid' attribute with value 'status-attachment-mentions-input'.

If you really need to use xpath, try this:
`"//[@data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']"`. You can also use css selector and find yo element like this:

```
inputField = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']")
```

Comment: Not working :(

File "D:/untitled/AllegroTest.py", line 27
    newpost = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-testid="status-attachment-mentions-input"]")
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Bad brackets:
Correct version: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']")


The same error like before:
Unable to locate element: [data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']

Comment: i'll edit an answer. Use single quotes instead of double around "status-at‌​tachment-mentions-in‌​put".

Comment: The same error like before:
Unable to locate element: [data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']

Comment: Can you post a picture of an element you want to locate? So that we are sure we talk about same things?

Comment: Would be great if you marked my answer as useful if it helped @PythonLearn :)